# String to JSONObject and back to String without losing UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, utf-8

I've got the following `result` in `String`

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "opening_hours" : {
         "open_now" : true,
         "weekday_text" : [
            "Monday: 8:00 AM – 7:00 PM",
            "Tuesday: 8:00 AM – 7:00 PM",
            "Wednesday: 8:00 AM – 2:30 PM",
            "Thursday: 8:00 AM – 7:00 PM",
            "Friday: 8:00 AM – 7:30 PM",
            "Saturday: 8:00 AM – 6:00 PM",
            "Sunday: Closed"
         ]
      }
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

which I convert to a `JSONObject` using

```
JSONObject resultJSON = new JSONObject(result);
```

I want to get the value of inner `weekday_text` key but it seems that the final output is not in `UTF-8` (`\u2013` unicode characters appear instead):

```
System.out.println(resultJSON.getJSONObject("result").getJSONObject("opening_hours").getJSONArray("weekday_text").toString());

["Monday: 8:00 AM \u2013 7:00 PM","Tuesday: 8:00 AM \u2013 7:00 PM","Wednesday: 8:00 AM \u2013 2:30 PM","Thursday: 8:00 AM \u2013 7:00 PM","Friday: 8:00 AM \u2013 7:30 PM","Saturday: 8:00 AM \u2013 6:00 PM","Sunday: Closed"]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The final output not being in UTF8 might be because of how `toString` is implemented. Try print one single item of the array.

Comment: You are right. `resultJSON.getJSONObject("result").getJSONObject("opening_hours").getJSONArray("weekday_text").getString(0)` gives a `UTF-8` encoded result. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing unicode escape sequences because of how `toString` is implemented. It is implemented this way probably to make it clear which characters are in the string, which makes it easier to debug your code, because sometimes different code points can look very similar.

The actual strings are still unescaped. Printing individual strings in the array will not show escape sequences:

```
System.out.println(resultJSON.getJSONObject("result").getJSONObject("opening_hours").getJSONArray("weekday_text").getString(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a OutputStreamWriter to manage the output encoding.

```
JSONObject resultJSON = new JSONObject(result);    
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "utf-8");
resultJSON.write(writer);
writer.flush();

String jSONStringUTF8 = new String(out.toByteArray(),"utf-8");
JSONObject newJSON = new JSONObject(jSONStringUTF8);
String value = newJSON.getString("content");
```